# How to visualize/read string messages from Rosbag

Tags: ros, rviz, rosbag, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have received a bag file from a colleague and i need to analyze it. The file looks like this. [image: image description]

How can i visualize this in rviz ? What type shoul i select here instead of point cloud ? [image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287001/how-to-visualize/read-string-messages-from-rosbag/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
Note: please review the [support guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support). Posting screenshots of textual content is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How can i visualize this in rviz ?

`std_msgs/String` does not have a display type in RViz at the moment. It would also seem to be difficult, as plain strings do not carry any intrinsic semantic meaning (ie: automated interpretation is rather difficult).

More specifically, RViz renders messages in a 3D context, so it requires spatial information (initially) to be able to do that. It uses the `frame_id` field (ie: TF) in incoming messages for that.

`std_msgs/String` does not have that, so it cannot be visualised like this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
Note also that what you're running into is a result of the (mis)use of messages and the reason that using semantically meaningful and appropriate messages is always strongly encouraged.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-03-29**:
Thanks for the explanation. I thought the same as well.

Then how can i atleast read this data ? one way is definitely to convert it into a csv file. I tried the following :`rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic > data.txt` but it gives a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Any idea ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
I'm not sure how well supported unicode/utf-8 is right now. If you have used characters from extended character sets this might cause problems.

It shouldn't though, so if you can create an MWE, you should report it.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-03-29**:
Yes, i guess there are some chinese characters in it but i am not sure.

- How can i check the contents of this bag file ?
- If you look at the image above, the bagfile has a topic called `/perception/kouliang` and the message type is `sim_l3_msg/kouliang`. I do not actually know what is it ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
re: get at the contents of the bag: if you `play` the bag, can you `rostopic echo ..` the topics in question?

re: msg type: you would have to ask your colleague. That is a custom message, so he should know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the `rqt` plugin "Topic Monitor" to subscribe to any message and show the content of the fields. It is basically the graphical equivalent of the already mentioned command line tool `ros topic echo`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-29**:
This is a good suggestion, but technically not an answer ;) The OP specifically asked how to visualise `std_msgs/String` in RViz.